# SQL query isn't displaying correct data

Tags: sql, contains

I have this table:

```
Recipe = (idR, recipeTitle, prepText, cuisineType, mealType)
Ingredient = (idI, ingrDesc)
RecipIngr = (idR*, idI*)
```

and I'm trying to display idR and recipe title that contains ingredients honey or mustard. Here is my query

```
select idr, recipetitle
from recipe
where idr IN (select idr from recpingr where idi =
(select distinct idr from ingredient where ingrdesc like '%honey%'))
INTERSECT
select idr, recipetitle
from recipe
where idr IN (select idr from recpingr where idi =
(select distinct idr from ingredient where ingrdesc like '%mustard%'))
ORDER BY idr;
```

For some reason this won't display the correct data and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any help? Is there something wrong with my query?

Comment: Please show us some sample data, the result of your query and why you would consider the "correct" data. Ideally on http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this help?

```
SELECT r.idr, r.recipetitle
FROM recipe r
INNER JOIN recipingr ring
    ON ring.idr = r.idr
INNER JOIN ingredient ing
    ON ing.idi = ring.idi
WHERE ing.ingrdesc LIKE '%honey%'
OR ingrdesc LIKE '%mustard%'
ORDER BY r.idr
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you overengineered it.  Why not something like this:

```
select idr, recipetitle
from recipe r join recipInbg ri on r.idr = ir.idr
join ingredient i on ri.idI = i.idI
where ingrdesc like '%honey%'
or ingrdesc like '%mustard%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
select r.idr, r.recipeTitle from recipe r, ingredient i, recipIngr ri
    where r.idR=ri.idR and ri.idI=i.idI and 
    (i.ingrDesc like '%honey%' or i.ingrDesc like '%mustard%')
```